# Зачем нужен ActivityMainBinding?

Tags: java, android

Я создал приложение на C++ в android studio. В написанном коде используется класс `ActivityMainBinding`, которого нет в шаблонах для Java. С его помощью можно получать элементы из xml, но можно сделать это без него, как в обычном приложении. Зачем нужен этот класс?

Comment: Чтобы не пользоваться findViewById !

Comment: @unknown, а мне нравится. Думаю продолжу как обычно.

Comment: К сожалению, Java не поддерживает множественного наследования. И когда вам, например, придется работать с фрагментом(который будет наследоваться от класса `Fragment`), работа с `findViewById()` вам будет не доступна. И вы тогда будете благодарны, что существует такой прекрасный механизм, как `databinding`. Поймите, если в языки что-то добавляют, то это делают не просто потому что нравится, а потому что это имеет спрос.

Comment: @SelectionForCollection это не совсем правда, в фрагменте доступно `view`, у которого и можно вызвать `findViewById`, `getView().findViewById()` (естественно после onCreateView и до onDestroyView)

Comment: Дело в том что когда у тебя много виюшка  тебе придется всех импортировать, это как-то не удобно, лично я всегда использую binding по мне  это очень удобно